# Booting ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64 from stick on my win10 notebook fails

Tags: boot, usb, windows-10

I have downloaded ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso and made a bootable stick.
My win10 notebook startdt to boot but eventually stopped with the message:
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:30.1-4ubuntu6) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(intramfs)

what is wrong?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Have you updated UEFI from vendor and if SSD, the SSD firmware?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Remake a different Ubuntu version LiveUSB for testing on that USB Flash drive.

Get an ISO file for a supported 'flavour' of 20.04 with a different Desktop (not the standard Ubuntu GNOME). Download @  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours .

The ISO used to make a LiveUSB should be [checked for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) as per Canonical's instructions.

Make it following Canonical's (Ubuntu's publishers) instructions on [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu), on a [Windows PC](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)  or on a [Mac](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos).

Once you remake the LiveUSB, boot from it, and see if the problem still occurs.